# how do i copy the value of a function that returns random values?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i'm trying to turn password into a hashed one, while keeping the original as well.

it seems that the two versions i try to return are not the same(even with deep copy, which i removed.)

```
def publish_rando(pub_id):
    rand_user = rando() #just a random string generator function
    rand_pass = rando() #just a random string generator function

    hashed_pass = _hash.bcrypt.hash(rand_pass) #hashed version of the random pass

    pub_pass = _models.pubUser(pub_id = pub_id, rand_user = rand_user, rand_pass = rand_pass)
    pub_hash = _models.pubUser(pub_id = pub_id, rand_user = rand_user, rand_pass = hashed_pass)
    
    return {'pub_hash': pub_hash, 'pub_pass': pub_pass}
```

what i get:

```
{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f20e21486a0>, 'pub_id': '57', 'rand_user': '5uJm#<B>WYu?', 'rand_pass': '$2b$12$tHRolNUYQZ6XJm27UZaXTO7SKmJKAbHaqH97DbKQxvMrw79pAK9t.'}
{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f20e2148490>, 'pub_id': '57', 'rand_user': 'J*gne5Nm#B<2', 'rand_pass': 'sjM%OvAtHg>8'}
```

notice that the user is different, which tells me that the password is not the same either.

_models.pubUser is a sqlalchemy model:

```
class pubUser(Base):
    __table__ = Table('pub_user', metadata,
                    autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

the call:

```
pub_rand_hashed = _crud.publish_rando(d['pub_id']).get('pub_hash') #this creates another sqlalchemy row object
pub_rand_unhashed = _crud.publish_rando(d['pub_id']).get('pub_pass') #this creates another sqlalchemy row object

print(pub_rand_hashed.__dict__, pub_rand_unhashed.__dict__)
```

Comment: what is `_models.pubUser()` and how are you calling the function?

Comment: @drum it's a sqlalchemy class.., so basically i'm just attaching the values of rand_pass and hashed_pass to class attributes.  and im just printing both returned values to see what's up

Comment: What is `rando`, what type of thing does it return and why does that thing need to be deep-copied?

Comment: When you use `deepcopy()` the result should *not* be the same as the original. So why is that unexpected?

Comment: @Barmar ok, maybe im misunderstanding...https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/  i thought deepcopy makes a copy of the values instead of pointing at the same object??? what is the alternative?

Comment: @kaya3 rando is a raandom word generator.  so i'm trying to capture the value, instead of having it run the function twice and give me different outcomes

Comment: That's correct. So the copy is *not* the same object as the original. What don't understand about that?

Comment: If it's a random string, there's no point in making a copy. Strings are immutable.

Comment: @barmar i only started using deepcopy as an attempt at solution.  without deepcopy i get the same thing: two different users which means the password wont match the hash either.  it seems that when i create a new instances of _models.pubUser, the rando() function is called and gives me a different value.  so im looking for a fix

Comment: If the user already has a hashed password saved in the DB, you shouldn't be hashing the password in the first place. You only hash the password when creating the user the first time.

Comment: When authenticating a user, you get the salt from the hashed password in the DB, hash the entered password with that salt, and compare with the one from the DB.

Comment: @Barmar it's a bit different from what ur describing.  the user publishes on the website, and a user/pass is automatically created.  the pass is hashed and the user/hash are put into the db, while the user/pass that were generated are returned to the user for him/her to save - with the option to change.

Comment: That's essentially the same, except that the password is generated automatically instead of being entered by the user. The rest of the process is the same: You only re-hash the password when the user changes it.

Comment: @barmar i would like it hashed incase they dont change it.  in any case, im still trying to figure out why i cant reuse the same value of the random word generator...

Comment: You're asking why one object has `'rand_user': '5uJm#<B>WYu?'` and the other has `'rand_user': 'J*gne5Nm#B<2'`? That's not possible if they're coming from the same call to `publish_rando()`.

Comment: @Barmar yes! thats exactly what im trying to figure out... it's the same call:
print(pub_rand_hashed.__dict__, pub_rand_unhashed.__dict__)

Comment: This must be something SQLAlchemy is doing. You're putting the same `rand_user` value in both objects, something else must be replacing it.

Comment: @barmar ok good to know. i tried to make a deepcopy of the sqlalchemy instance as well, and change the attribute value but it doesn't do it.

Comment: Is `pub_id` the primary key of `pubUser`? You shouldn't be using the same ID for two different objects.

Comment: You also shouldn't be storing unhashed passwords in the DB. The DB should just contain the hashed password, you only send the plaintext password to the user.

Comment: @barmar it's a foreign key...but the db creates an autoincremented primary key when i add to the table. however, in this case, im only going to be adding the hashed model, while returning the unhashed model to the user

Comment: Don't use ORM objects for general application data, they're just for storing and retrieving database values.

Comment: good to know, it was a two birds/one stone sort of deal... thanks for taking the time btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this was a total rookie mistake, but maybe it'll help someone.

@Barmar was keen to point out that if you don't call the function twice, a different answer is not possible.

well, i changed this:

```
pub_rand_hashed = _crud.publish_rando(d['pub_id']).get('pub_hash') #this creates another sqlalchemy row object
pub_rand_unhashed = _crud.publish_rando(d['pub_id']).get('pub_pass') #this creates another sqlalchemy row object
```

to this:

```
pub_rand = _crud.publish_rando(d['pub_id']) #this creates another sqlalchemy row object
pub_rand_unhashed = pub_rand.get('pub_pass')
pub_rand_hashed = pub_rand.get('pub_hash')
```